# Getting error in executing commands using ProcessBuilder in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ioexception, processbuilder, runtime.exec

IDE used: IntelliJ 
System OS: Windows 
Commands tried: ProcessBuilder, Runtime.exec()

I am executing Main.java file (mentioned below). It executes perfectly in terminal but in IntelliJ, it throws the following error. The same happens with both ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec().

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe"
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at TestSample.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is it happening? Can someone help me resolve this issue?

**Main.java**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,IOException{

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "This is ProcessBuilder Example");
        Process p=builder.start();
        int errcode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Program is executed successfully?"+(errcode == 0 ?"No":"Yes"));
        System.out.println("Echo Output:\n" + output(p.getInputStream()));

    }
    private static String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

This code is retrieved from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/

Answer (score 3):

`echo` is not a valid executable, instead it's a command provided by the command line shell (`cmd.exe`).

In order to run this command from the other processes you have to start `cmd.exe` and pass the arguments to it.

The working code for Windows would look like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "echo", "This is ProcessBuilder Example from JCG");
```

For other operating systems you would need to replace `cmd.exe` with `/bin/bash`, etc.

Comment: I tried in mac, but it is worked without /bin/bash. Do you think of any reason for that?

Comment: @Saranya macOS probably has `echo` executable file while Windows doesn't.